# HP-UX terminal is disabled

Tags: hp-ux

One of my team mate created an ID on an old HP-UX server and upon multiple fail login, he got his ID locked and the terminal locked as well.

Now, when I login, it says Terminal is disabled -- see Account Administrator.

How do I go about unlocking the terminal and his ID?

Comment: So he locked out the root account?

Comment: No, he just locked out his own account. The root and backup root ID is still available.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the "unlocking the terminal", but you can unlock the user account with:

```
userdbset -d -u <username> auth_failures
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't normally administer this system, so you may find it easier to use the  `sam` command to launch [System Management Homepage](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02264923/c02264923.pdf), a menu-driven admin application.

If you're running a very old version of HP-UX, the `sam` command will actually run the older System Administration Managerserver" application.

Comment: Hi, I have used the Accounts for Users and Groups option in sam before. But may I know where do I unlock the terminal from the sam application?